# Entity Framework MySQL tinyint(1) System.Boolean.Parse FormatException

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm using **EntityFramework 6** in my C# **model-first** project which using a **MySQL database.**
Everything was fine and I could generate my database without problem.

Then I modified my **.edmx** file using the designer and here started the problems I have.

- First the designer doesn't update the **CSDL content** and the **C-S mapping content** sections of the .edmx file anymore.
  So I updated the content myself and could finally compile the project.

Here's the **.edmx** file as it is right now and what it looks like in the designer:

EDMX File: http://pastebin.com/Xer9UyNR

And here is the link for the designer view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcv9W.png

- Second (and most important one), I get a FormatException when EF tries to get a tinyint coming from my database and change its type into a boolean.

```
    à ArmoireOutils.App.OnNavigateMessageHandler(OnNavigateMessage message) dans c:\Users\JB\Desktop\CodingFrance\ArmoireOutils\ArmoireOutils\App.xaml.cs:line 101System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean..
    à System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
    à System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
    à System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
    à MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType)
    à MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal)
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
    à lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
    à lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MaterializeRow()
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext()
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement()
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.ReadElement()
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext()
    à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
    à System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.&lt;GetElementFunction&gt;b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
    à System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
    à System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
    à ArmoireOutils.Services.DataService.GetCupboardByGuid(String guid) dans c:\Users\JB\Desktop\CodingFrance\ArmoireOutils\ArmoireOutils\Services\DataService.cs:line 202
```

Here is my **GetCupboardByGUID** method:

```
public Cupboard GetCupboardByGuid(String guid)
    {
        using (var context = new ArmoireOutilsEntities())
        {
            var cupboard = (from a in context.Cupboards
                where a.GUID.Equals(guid)
                select a)
                .Include("ResidentTools")
                .Include("Tools")
                .Include("Users") //If I remove this, .SingleOrDefault() works fine.
                .SingleOrDefault(); //Throw FormatException when getting the User.Active value from the database.

            if (cupboard != null)
                cupboard.RefreshLists();

            return cupboard;
        }
    }
```

And here is my User class generated by the .edmx tt:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Tools = new ObservableCollection<Tool>();
        this.Cupboards = new ObservableCollection<Cupboard>();
        this.Active = true;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public short Type { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public short Gender { get; set; }
    public short LangId { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastConnection { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DisableDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual Lang Lang { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Cupboard> Cupboards { get; set; }
}
```

So I guess EF is iterating over all users from the DB who are in the **cupboarduser** (the table linking a **user** to a **cupboard** for the many-to-many relationship) and when it comes to set the **Active** value for the first user, it gets 1 from the DB getting it as a **String** first and then try to parse that string into a boolean using **System.Boolean.Parse** but thaat method doesn't support numbers like "1" for true (the field in the DB is a **tinyint(1)**).

So why EF is not able to understand it was a tinyint so he can't use it in **System.Boolean.Parse** ?

I tried to regenerate the entire **.edmx** file from the database => Same exception

I tried to regenerate the entire **.edmx** file from scratch => Same exception

I don't understand why because I didn't modify the User model so the **Active** field was already there and was working just fine.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance.

Best regards,
theCivilian

Comment: You have to tell MySql to treat tinyint as boolean, in the connection string.

Comment: @GertArnold, Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunatly it says **"The 'treat tiny as boolean' keyword is not supported."** Also this value is **true** by default according to the documentation. (I'm using **MySQL-Connector 6.8.3**

Answer (score 16):

Configure the datatype on a specific Entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                  .Property(p => p.Active)
                  .HasColumnType("bit");
```

or general:

```
modelBuilder.Properties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            .Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("bit"));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if we are doing DB first? Not sure where to apply the change. Help?

Comment: This works like a charm for me, i used TINYINT(1) but that doesn't work when i tried to retrieve data, but using BIT type works fine for both, saving and retrieving data.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved using the `Column` data attribute within the Entity.

```
[Column("Active", TypeName = "bit")]
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool Active { get; set; }
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no need for the default value attribute on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually had to set TreatTinyAsBoolean=false in the connection string and my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this DB first, simply change the TINYINT(1) types to BIT(1), assuming you really want a Boolean.  You may have to update the default values also (to bit syntax such as b'0').  EF will still translate these to Boolean values in your entities.