# FormatException when using multiple Include() methods in MySQL Linq Query EF6

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to execute a LINQ query and using `Include()` multiple times to pull related information.

**It works fine if I do the following query:**

```
var usersQuizzes = this.Context.EntitySet<Quiz>()
                    .Include(x => x.Questions)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizVersion)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizPasswords)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizVersion.Questions)
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
```

**But I get an error if I have it like this:**

```
var usersQuizzes = this.Context.EntitySet<Quiz>()
                    .Include(x => x.Questions)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizVersion)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizPasswords)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizVersion.Questions)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizVersions) // Added this
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
```

**or this:**

```
var usersQuizzes = this.Context.EntitySet<Quiz>()
                    .Include(x => x.Questions)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizVersion)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizPasswords)
                    .Include(x => x.QuizVersion.Questions)
                    .Include(x => x.ResultDescriptions) // Added this instead
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
```

**or this:**

```
 var usersQuizzes = this.Context.EntitySet<Quiz>()
                        .Include(x => x.QuizVersions)
                        .Include(x => x.ResultDescriptions)
                        .Include(x => x.QuizPasswords)
                        .Take(20)
                        .ToList();
```

**But it works if I strip out QuizPasswords:**

```
 var usersQuizzes = this.Context.EntitySet<Quiz>()
                        .Include(x => x.QuizVersions)
                        .Include(x => x.ResultDescriptions)
                        .Take(20)
                        .ToList();
```

### Error Message

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

**Quiz.cs**

```
public partial class Quiz
    {
        public Quiz()
        {
            this.TakerAnswers = new List<TakerAnswer>();
            this.FeaturedQuizzes = new List<FeaturedQuiz>();
            this.PersonalityOutcomes = new List<PersonalityOutcome>();
            this.PossibleAnswers = new List<PossibleAnswer>();
            this.Questions = new List<Question>();
            this.QuizLinks = new List<QuizLink>();
            this.QuizPasswords = new List<QuizPassword>();
            this.QuizSubmissions = new List<QuizSubmission>();
            this.QuizVersions = new List<QuizVersion>();
            this.ResultDescriptions = new List<ResultDescription>();
            this.Takers = new List<Taker>();
            this.PersonalityResultImages = new List<PersonalityResultImage>();
            this.PersonalityShareImages = new List<PersonalityShareImage>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> QuizVersionId { get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(QuizType.Scored)]
        public QuizType QuizType { get; set; }

        public int CreatedTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BackgroundId { get; set; }

        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string UrlId { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool PasswordsDisabled { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool SharedFacebook { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool SharedTwitter { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool ShowCorrections { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool ShowBreakdown { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string ShareImage { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> QuizLinkId { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool ForceShareImage { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int ShareCount { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(BackgroundAlign.Top)]
        public BackgroundAlign BackgroundAlign { get; set; }

        public string BackgroundColour { get; set; }
        public string TextColour { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TakerAnswer> TakerAnswers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FeaturedQuiz> FeaturedQuizzes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalityOutcome> PersonalityOutcomes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizLink> QuizLinks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizPassword> QuizPasswords { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizSubmission> QuizSubmissions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizVersion> QuizVersions { get; set; }
        public virtual QuizBackground QuizBackground { get; set; }
        public virtual QuizLink QuizLink { get; set; }
        public virtual QuizVersion QuizVersion { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ResultDescription> ResultDescriptions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Taker> Takers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalityResultImage> PersonalityResultImages { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalityShareImage> PersonalityShareImages { get; set; }
    }
```

**QuizVersion.cs**

```
public partial class QuizVersion
    {
        public QuizVersion()
        {
            this.TakerAnswers = new List<TakerAnswer>();
            this.FeaturedQuizzes = new List<FeaturedQuiz>();
            this.PersonalityOutcomes = new List<PersonalityOutcome>();
            this.PossibleAnswers = new List<PossibleAnswer>();
            this.Questions = new List<Question>();
            this.QuizSubmissions = new List<QuizSubmission>();
            this.Takers = new List<Taker>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int QuizId { get; set; }
        public string QuizName { get; set; }
        public string QuizIntro { get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
        public bool Public { get; set; }
        public int CreatedTime { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TakerAnswer> TakerAnswers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FeaturedQuiz> FeaturedQuizzes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalityOutcome> PersonalityOutcomes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizSubmission> QuizSubmissions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Taker> Takers { get; set; }
    }
```

**ResultDescription.cs**

```
public partial class ResultDescription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuizId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Percentage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
}
```

I thought it might be some dodgy values within my database, but I've checked all of the `bool` type values within my POCO classes and they all seem to be type `tinyint(1)` and set to either `1` or `0` and no nulls.

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and used this workaround, in your first error example:

```
var usersQuizzes = this.Context.EntitySet<Quiz>()
                .Include(x => x.Questions)
                .Include(x => x.QuizVersion)
                .Include(x => x.QuizPasswords)
                .Include(x => x.QuizVersion.Questions);

this.Context.Entry(userQuizes).Collection("QuizVersions").Load();

userQuizes.Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: It works, although not as efficient as one would hope. Best add the bug reports for historical reference. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68886, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76466

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make my code work by switching the include order and putting the bugged include first (in your case it is x.QuizPasswords)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution forcing the property to 'bit' default 'false'. I changed the data type in Mysql. Tinyint -> Bit.

```
[Column("Active", TypeName = "bit")]
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool Active { get; set;
```

The link reference:

[Entity Framework MySQL tinyint(1) System.Boolean.Parse FormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021287/entity-framework-mysql-tinyint1-system-boolean-parse-formatexception/31534825#31534825)