# EF-MySQL: Multiple Include Statements with TinyInt(1) Field - Throws System.FormatException

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Quite a strange behavior by Entity Framework while trying to execute a query with multiple include statements! The database has been setup using code-first. All the boolean properties are created as tinyint(1) by default and everything works fine as long as the include statements are limited.

There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021287/entity-framework-mysql-tinyint1-system-boolean-parse-formatexception). But that forces the EF to use BIT column type instead of tinyint(1). Unfortunately, the column type needs to be retained as tinyint(1) due to some constraints.

I have created a sample project where the error could be reproduced.

**Model**:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Entity()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class Designation : Entity
{
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Designation()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Address : Entity
{
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Address()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Department : Entity
{
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Task : Entity
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Entity
{
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Designation Designation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        this.Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }
}
```

Now when I run the following query, it raises the exception. If one of the include statements is commented out, the query runs to completion without any errors!

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
    {
       var employees = context.Set<Employee>()
                              .Include(it => it.Department)
                              .Include(it => it.Department.Employees)
                              .Include(it => it.Address)
                              .Include(it => it.Designation)
                              .Include(it => it.Designation.Employees)
                              .Include(it => it.Tasks)
                              .ToList();
    }
```

Here's the *exception* & *stack trace*:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.`

```
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MaterializeRow()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.ReadElement()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at EF.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ashin_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\EF.Console\Program.cs:line 52
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

As a work around, I had to segregate the include statements into multiple queries and run them separately, which isn't so optimal.

Please suggest a better solution! Thanks in advance!

Versions used: EF - **6.1.3** MySQL - **5.7.17** MySQL Connector - **6.9.9**

Comment: are you sure all your datatypes are correct?

Comment: yes, they are correct!